# Error "multiple definition of" when trying to make a mock library

Tags: c++, arduino

This may be Arduino specific because the most obvious solution would be to have a different Make file. However, I am working with a team of people who are all pretty green in the ways of C++ and I'd like to not change the current compile setup/workflow.

### The goal

1. Have MyClass defined in MyClass.h and MyClass.cpp that uses hardware that not all developers have access to at all times.
2. Have MyClass defined in Mock_MyClass.h and Mock_MyClass.cpp that defines the exact same interface, but sends output to Serial.
3. Not have to move/rename files to get a successful compile.

### The problem

I have everything working except #3 above. If I use `#include "MyClass.h"` in my code and `for f in Mock_MyClass.*; do mv $f $f.hide; done` on the command line, it avoids the error. Then to use the real hardware I have to reverse it. If I have to do that on the command line, it'd be easier to overwrite symlinks... but some team members are using Windows. **S#&$*^!!**

### The ask

Can I get the Arduino IDE to ignore the *.h and *.cpp files that are not `#include`-ed in my sketch so that it compiles fine with only a change to the include?

Comment: cpp files should not be #include'd

Comment: probably what you should do is have a single `MyClass.h` that defines a single interface, and have either `MyClass.cpp` or `Mock_MyClass.cpp` linked in depending whether you are building a mock version or not. You could either control that via the build environment, or use a `-D` define switch

Comment: Why you do not want to have a base abstract class, subclass it to `MyClass` and `Mock_MyClass` and just pass around the pointer to the version you need?

Comment: @Petr, that sounds interesting. I'm just not sure how to do that. My only C/C++ experience in the last 20 years has been recently with Arduino. We are not often faced with those kinds of challenges.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, You are right in that I don't need 2 .h files. I could get rid of the other one, but I don't know how to build in a .cpp file that doesn't match the name of the .h file. As far as "build environment" or "a `-D` define switch" is concerned, I don't know how I could do that with Arduino.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky, I've googled the following article for example: http://clean-cpp.org/mock-objects/ . Note how they have a base class, `second_clock`, and two subclasses.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky your build environment will have a place where you specify which `.cpp` files form part of your project. The `.h` files can be named anything, they way they work is that `#include "foo.h"` in another file causes a text replacement of that line with the contents of `foo.h`, so clearly it does not matter what the file is called.